# How to split a string in Android according to a given condition?

Tags: java, android, string

I have a string, `12-512-2-15-487-9-98` and I want to split into two strings such below:

```
str1="12-512-2";
str2="15-487-9-98";
```

That means the first string will contain the characters before third `-`, and the second string will contain the remaining characters after that.

How can I do this?
I tried that by using `split("-")` and concat `str[0]+"-"+str[1]+"-"+str[2]`
but I want easier answer.

Comment: are the amount of digits are always the same? or it can change

Comment: Which language? Kotlin or java?

Comment: @Dor No,they aren't. But the amount of "-" are the same.

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess using regex seems easier?

```
String line = "12-512-2-15-487-9-98";
String pattern = "(\\d+-\\d+-\\d+)-(\\d+-\\d+-\\d+-\\d+)";


Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

if (m.find( )) {
  System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
  System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
  System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
} else {
  System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

The value of `m.group(1)` and `m.group(2)` are what you want.

Another way is using [StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#ordinalIndexOf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) in Apache Commons Lang library to find the index of the 3rd occurrence of `-` and call `substring` with the index obtained.

Comment: Thanks your reply, but I want a way to split third special character directly.

Comment: Please find my updated reply above, I hope that may help you :)

Comment: Yes, it's near to my answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
String text = "12-512-2-15-487-9-98";
int pos = text.indexOf('-', 1 + text.indexOf('-', 1 + text.indexOf('-')));
String first = text.substring(0, pos);
String second = text.substring(pos+1);

System.out.println(first); // 12-512-2
System.out.println(second); // 15-487-9-98
```

Comment: Thanks your reply, but I want a way to split third special character directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by `str.indexOf()` function where you need to pass character and starting index of your string

For your example

```
int indexofSecondOccurance=str.indexOf("-", str.indexOf("-") + 1);  
int finalIndex = str.indexOf("-", indexofSecondOccurance + 1));
```

After that, you can split your string by `substring()`.

Comment: Thanks your reply, but I want a way to split third special character directly.

Answer (score 0):

the idea is to iterate the string and increase the counter when you see "-" 
 at the 3rd "-" it will split the string by using substring and provide the index you found the 3rd "-" at.

It might need a little adjustment to the index if it isn't splitting it as it should.

it should look like this:

```
     String temp = "12-345-678-44-55-66-77";
    int counter = 0;
    String string1 = "";
    String string2 = "";

    for(int i = 0 ; i<temp.length()-1;i++){
        if(temp.charAt(i) == '-'){
            counter++;
        }
        if(counter == 3){
            string1 = temp.substring(0,i-1);
            string2 = temp.substring(i+1,temp.length()-1);
            System.out.println(string1+" "+string2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want a simple solution that gives me a sub string from third special character of "-".